# clang doesn't see base class constructors pulled in via typedef

Tags: c++, c++11, using-declaration, inherited-constructors

The following code

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
struct V : public std::vector<T>
{
    using Impl = std::vector<T>;
    using typename Impl::vector; // the constructors
};

int main()
{
    std::string empty;
    V<std::string> meow{42UL, empty};
}
```

Is compiled fine by GCC 8.2 (calls the `size_t, string` constructor).
However, clang up to 14 rejects it with

```
<source>:14:20: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'V<std::string>' (aka 'V<basic_string<char>>')
    V<std::string> meow{42UL, empty};
                   ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:5:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
struct V : public std::vector<T>
       ^
<source>:5:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
<source>:5:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit default constructor) not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were provided
```

as if V had no constructors: https://godbolt.org/z/M91zb6Pjr

Replacing `using typename Impl::vector;` with `using Impl::Impl;` makes clang accept the code. What is going on here?

Comment: The constructors inheriting is done via `using B::B` inside of `A`'s class definition, where `A` is a derived class and `B` is its base class. Where did you find `using typename B::vector;` form from?

Comment: @TheDreamsWind - Presumably they found it by being C++-savvy enough to know about the injected class name, in both regular classes and in class templates.

Comment: Btw, if this entire exercise is to avoid repeating template arguments, then the injected class names in both `V` and `vector` obviates the need. It's just somewhat less obvious due to how dependent names behave in templates. `using V::vector::vector;` is standard and works in all compilers (well, that I tried on godbolt), without needing to specify all template arguments.

Comment: I found the `using typename B::vector` in code written by a cow orker. Said code was never seen by clang until yesterday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the recent resolution of [CWG issue 2070](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2070) it is not possible anymore to use a dependent alias to inherit the constructor in a `using` declaration, except if repeating the name of the alias.

You *must* use the same identifier to name the base class as you are using to refer to the constructor (the last *unqualified-id* after the *nested-name-specifier*), for example:

```
using std::vector<T>::vector;
```

or making use of the lookup of the injected class name of the base class in `V`:

```
using V::vector::vector;
```

or by a special rule for using-declarators the name of the alias may also be repeated instead of using the injected class name if it is dependent:

```
using Impl::Impl;
```

(see https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#class.qual-1.2 and https://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#1.sentence-3)

If you write `using typename Impl::vector;` instead it is not inheriting a constructor, but instead `vector` is going to be interpreted as a type named by the injected class name in `vector<T>`, which then is imported as the name `vector` into the class scope.

This requirement is to avoid that the same `using` line will cause the constructor to be inherited sometimes and a type name to be imported other times, depending on the specialization of the template.

Basically, after the resolution you know that the `using` declaration with a dependent nested-name-specifier is inheriting a constructor if and only if it is ending in `A::A` or `A::A` for some name `A` (potentially with additional template argument lists, etc.).

It seems that Clang has always implemented it this way, although I think it wasn't really correct according to the standard before the resolution of the issue.

Comment: Considering it was an issue reported by Richard Smith, it's hardly a surprise that Clang already behaved in a way that makes sense to him.